# History of the delta potential barrier in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, probability

I'm interested in finding something out about the history of the problem of the delta potential barrier in QM. Who was the first to propose this problem, and perhaps any particular motivation for it. References that I could read and quote would be excellent. I am aware of some of the usual motivations for using it, but any examples that come to mind are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a near-exact duplicate of http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/history-of-delta-barrier-in-qm, into which it will be merged.